# Schema validation android

Tags: java, android, validation, xsd

In `java` there is class `SchemaFactory` which is used for schema validation but it is not available in android. Is there any other option available?

Answer (score 1):

So long as the `SchemaFactory` class requires no JNI code you can just import its `.jar` file into your Android project and use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no XSchema support in Android. This was true in version 1.0, and I just looked at the changes in 1.5 and no changes have been made to any of the xml packages, so it appears to me it's still true. I don't have the source > 1.0 though.

In the 1.0 source code there's the following comments in various parser classes:

```
// TODO No XSchema support in Android 1.0. Maybe later.
```

So you'll have to bundle your own classes or skip schema validation altogether for now. It's probably not a high priority feature for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the validator from the XML implementation directly. Either see if you can find the validator classes in whatever XML parser comes with Android, or use a standalone validator like [MSV](https://msv.dev.java.net/)