# Validate XML Schema in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to validate some xml files in the resources of an Android application against an XML Schema. Although [there is](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) an available API to create instances of SchemaFactory, there seems to be no implementation for XML Schema, as stated by the answers to these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129934/schemafactory-doesnt-support-w3c-xml-schema-in-platform-level-8), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801632/android-schema) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801144/android-schema-validation).

Are there any good and lightweight libraries to provide that functionality in the Android platform?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Lycia](http://code.google.com/p/lycia/). Its around 270 kb. Here is nice [step by step example](http://code.google.com/p/lycia/wiki/SmallCodeDemonstration) for schema validation. It creates a schema, a small XML referring to schema (via `schemaLocation`) and then an example to parse the xml with schema validation

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to explicitly validate a document against a specified XSD? I only seem to be able to do it through a validation aware parser, similar to the one in the example you provided.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your particular use case ?

Comment: I want to, given as input an XML and an XSD file, output a boolean stating whether the XML files validates against the given XML schema or not.

Comment: I am trying something, will post I succeed :).